# DialogFragment ignores OnBackPressedDispatcher

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

I'm trying to handle the back button in a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, which is a `DialogFragment`, using `'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0-alpha01'` and `'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'`.

`handleOnBackPressed()` is not called and the `DialogFragment` is dismissed. The `OnBackPressedCallback` is enabled when the back button is pressed.

I think the `DialogFragment` is intercepting the back button press, because the `ComponentActivity` never calls `mOnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed();`

Is there a way to override the `DialogFragment` handling of back button press?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, but I hope the library will take care of this usecase.

Create a custom `BottomSheetDialog`:

```
class BackPressBottomSheetDialog(context: Context, @StyleRes theme: Int, 
private val callback: BackPressBottomSheetDialogCallback) :
        BottomSheetDialog(context, theme) {

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (callback.shouldInterceptBackPress()) callback.onBackPressIntercepted()
        else super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

And its `interface`

```
interface BackPressBottomSheetDialogCallback {
    fun shouldInterceptBackPress(): Boolean
    fun onBackPressIntercepted()
}
```

Then in your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
private val dialogCallback = object : BackPressBottomSheetDialogCallback {
      override fun shouldInterceptBackPress(): Boolean {
        //TODO should you intercept the back button?
      }

      override fun onBackPressIntercepted() {
        //TODO what happens when you intercept the back button press
      }
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return BackPressBottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme, dialogCallback)
}
```

Answer (score 21):

It's really hard to understand what Google Android Dev making. Anyway, i found a solution without using interfaces.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return object : Dialog(requireContext(), theme) {
        override fun onBackPressed() {
            // handle back press
        }
    }
}
```

Just override the onCreateDialog and also override onBackPressed inside it.

Answer (score 7):

One more solution:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).also {
        val componentDialog = it as ComponentDialog
        componentDialog.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            val backPressedConsumed = yourLegacyLogic()
            if (backPressedConsumed.not()) {
                isEnabled = false
                requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

Back-pressed events are passed into the `dialog` of the `DialogFragment`, therefore you should register `OnBackpressedCallback` for the `dialog`.

Disabling the callback (`isEnabled = false`) allows you to prevent the consumption of the next back-pressed event.
Once you disabled the callback you're retriggering the back pressed-event (calling `requireActivity().onBackPressed()`) and it will be consumed by someone else, e.g. your navigation will pop the back stack.

After that, you should enable the callback (`isEnabled = true`) to receive the next back-pressed events.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for Kotlin:

Override below method in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
        setOnKeyListener { _: DialogInterface, keyCode: Int, keyEvent: KeyEvent ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // your code
                // return true if you want keep dialog visible
                // return false if you want to dismiss dialog anyway
                return@setOnKeyListener true
            }
            return@setOnKeyListener false
        }
    }
}
```