# Handling BottomSheetDialogFragment State

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have created one chatsheetfragment(Bottomsheetdialogfragment). Whenever I open it I'm calling all the chats and binding in `RecyclerView`. So, my problem is the chat sheet is always reloading from `onCreate()` which eventually results refreshing the fragment every time. how to stop it.

And I'm using `viewmodel` using dagger-hilt . `Viewmodel` instance is also creating every time.

Tried opening as singleton instance but not worked and now I'm opening like below

```
 private fun chatButton() {
    binding.chatIv.setOnClickListener {
        ChatSheetFragment().show(
            supportFragmentManager,
            ChatSheetFragment::class.java.simpleName
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe store your list in the parent activity and reload the list if only it is empty inside the ChatSheetFragment

Comment: Can you add code of ```ChatSheetFragment```

Answer (score 1):

With `ChatSheetFragment()`, a brand new fragment is getting created and therefore a brand new `ViewModel` in case that you bind this `ViewModel` to that fragment.

This can be solved by binding that `ChatSheetFragment` to the parent activity/fragment `ViewModel` that can host the updated list.

**So, in short:**

- Change the `ViewModel` in the `ChatSheetFragment` to either the parent fragment/activity (according to your desgin):

  i.e., instead of `ViewModelProvider(this)[MyChatViewModel::class.java]` you'd replace `this` with `requireParentFragment()` or `requireActivity()` and replace `MyChatViewModel` with the one of the parent fragment/activity.
- Move the list logic that you want to maintain from the chat fragment `ViewModel` to the parent `ViewModel`.

Another solution is not to create a brand new fragment with `ChatSheetFragment()` and just show the existing one; but not sure if that can affect the performance to keep it alive while you don't need it.

**Edit:**

> problem to me is bottomsheetfragment is detaching and destroying itself whenever it dismiss. what can i do so that it can not be destroyed

This is right; calling `dismiss()` or even setting the BottomSheetBehavior state to `STATE_HIDDEN` will destroy the fragment.

But there is a workaround to just hide the decorView of the dialogFragment window whenever you want to hide the chat fragment like the following:

```
val chatDialogFragment = ChatSheetFragment()
// Hide the bottom sheet dialog fragment
chatDialogFragment.dialog.hide(); // equivalent to dialog.window.decorView.visiblity = View.GONE
// Show the bottom sheet dialog fragment
chatDialogFragment.dialog.show // equivalent to dialog.window.decorView.visiblity = View.VISIBLE
```

But you need to handle the situations when the DialogFragment can hide; here is a couple ones:

- Dismiss on back press

Customize the dialog in `onCreateDialog()`:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return object : BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme) {
        override fun onBackPressed() {
            this@BottomSheetFragment.dialog?.hide()
        }
    }
}
```

- Dismiss on touch outside:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val outsideView =
        requireDialog().findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.touch_outside)
    isCancelable = false
    dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    outsideView.setOnTouchListener { _: View?, event: MotionEvent ->
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) dialog?.hide()
        false
    }
```

Whenever you want to show the fragment again; just show its dialog without re-instantiating it as described above

Comment: Hi actually i have implemented this one but problem to me is bottomsheetfragment is detaching and destroying itself whenever it dismiss. what can i do so that it can not be destroyed

Comment: You're right; not sure if you can hide the dialogFragment without destroying it;  I will try to test that out. for now you can go for the parent ViewModel.

Comment: Ok thanks that will be helpful for community

Comment: @SyedIbrahim Just updated the answer; but for me I'd go for the SharedViewModel described above.

Comment: There is an issue on using `onBackPressedDispatcher` in dialogFragment as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160036/dialogfragment-ignores-onbackpresseddispatcher) post

Comment: Zain you have any idea like iam subscribing to channel events from view model , iam getting some inconsistencies there like one event is invoking in fragment while other event is not invoking, as there is not at all difference in two events only names changed.

Comment: Can you open a question for this so that a one can check the code and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251562/discussion-between-syed-ibrahim-and-zain).